# WP register_post_type() Перестали отображаться кастомный посты в админке

Tags: php, wordpress

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что после создания 2-го кастомного типа записи в админке выводиться для редактирования (и отображается) только последний созданный пост. Подскажите, в чём иожет быть причина ?
[image: News]

Вот как в function.php делаю инициализацию

```
////// Football players
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_football_players' );
function register_post_type_football_players() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Football players',
        'singular_name' => 'Football player',
        'add_new' => 'Add football player',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new football player', // заголовок тега <title>
        'edit_item' => 'Redact football player',
        'new_item' => 'New football player',
        'all_items' => 'All football players',
        'view_item' => 'Watch football player on a site',
        'search_items' => 'Search football player',
        'not_found' =>  'Football player did not find',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No players in trash',
        'menu_name' => 'Football players' // ссылка в меню в админке
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'football-player', 'canlimacflix' ),
        'description' => __( 'All football players', 'canlimacflix' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, // показывать интерфейс в админке
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups', // иконка в меню
        'menu_position' => 5, // порядок в меню
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields',),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag'),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,

    );
    register_post_type('football-players', $args);
}


////// News pages
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_type_news' );
function register_post_type_news() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'News',
        'singular_name' => 'News single',
        'add_new' => 'Add news',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new news', // заголовок тега <title>
        'edit_item' => 'Redact news',
        'new_item' => 'New news',
        'all_items' => 'All news',
        'view_item' => 'Watch news on a site',
        'search_items' => 'Search news',
        'not_found' =>  'News did not find',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No news in trash',
        'menu_name' => 'News' // ссылка в меню в админке
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'news', 'canlimacflix' ),
        'description' => __( 'All news', 'canlimacflix' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, // показывать интерфейс в админке
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-info', // иконка в меню
        'menu_position' => 6, // порядок в меню
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments',  'revisions', 'custom-fields',),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag'),
        'publicly_queryable' => true,

    );
    register_post_type('news', $args);

}
```

И для Новостей и для Футболистов в админке только последняя созданная отображается. Перезагружал сервер, пересохранял Пермалинки, не помогает...

Comment: проблема явно не в этом месте, нужно копать глубже

Comment: Я потерялся... не знаю куда смотреть. Повесил тему на новую базу данных, не помогло. Опять же отображает только последние кастомные посты.

Comment: как продебажить
1.переключите тему на одну из стандартных и добавьте код регистрации постов.
если все норм то ищете в теме фильтры на изменение запроса. если не помогло
2. вырубайте все плагины и смотрите на результат

Comment: Да, на стандартной теме `twentytwentyone` работает корректно. Все кастомные посты отображаются.  Как искать "фильтры на изменение запроса" ? Как они могут называться?

Comment: вариантов может быть несколько... начните с pre_get_posts

Comment: Ага, спасибо, всё нашел. Мне ломало работу  функция  function custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive('football-players') || $query->is_category() ) {
        set_query_var('posts_per_page', 1);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );  Но без неё пагинация для страницы архиов Новостей теперь не работает (

Comment: @BlackStar1991 добавьте проверку на `is_admin()` в вашу функцию `custom_posts_per_page`. Например `if(is_admin()) { return; }`.

Comment: Да, спасибо @Simon это решило проблему